# Is there a way to improve python speed time?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, tweepy

So this is my code:

```
ckey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXX'
csecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
atoken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
asecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
client = discord.Client()
token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
PartAlert = 1314575666130694144

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)
counter = 2
recent_id = PartAlert #hardcode the last recent post id from the user
while counter == 2:
  recent_post = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'PartAlert', count = 1, since_id=recent_id, include_rts = True, tweet_mode='extended')
  if recent_post:
    last_post = recent_post[0].full_text
    print(last_post)
    print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Link(s) Found:")
    urls = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*(),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', last_post)
    if urls:
      for x in range(len(urls)):
        if urls[x][-1] == ':':
          urls[x] = urls[x][:-1]
        counter = 1
        print(urls[x])
    recent_id = recent_post[0].id

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  await client.get_channel(822734857272688651).send(urls[x])
  print(f"[{datetime.datetime.now()}] Send to Discord:")

counter = 2
client.run(token)
```

which gets everytime a new tweet of an user and post it to my discord. The problem with the code is that it takes way to long (3 seconds). So is there a way to make my code faster?

Comment: Have you done any profiling - do you know which bit is slow ?

Comment: https://ibb.co/B2yKZ48 - I think there is the part which takes to long. I check the time with datetime ( https://ibb.co/2j9nDW8 ) and it shows that this part takes 3 seconds

Comment: @Haider--you may want to add your clarification to your posted question or use a different site for code links.  This is because your provided links on imgbb provide some questionable (possibly offensive to some) unrelated advertisements.  Also, you should provide code in text not images.

Comment: instead of using findall - have you tried doing a simple loop around finditer() results ?